# How to close listening UDP sockets when mocha times-out?

Tags: node.js, udp, timeout, mocha.js

I have some tests which bind to a UDP port, e.g.

```
describe('the server', function() {
  it('should respond to a udp packet', function(done) {
    const udp = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

    udp.on('error', function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });

    udp.on('message', function(msg, rinfo) {
      console.log('msg', msg);
      console.log('rinfo', rinfo);
      // TODO: check the reply
      udp.close();
      done();
    });
    udp.bind();

    // send a request
    const bytes = Buffer.from("421a0800117860bc457f0100001a0653455256455222054d54303031", 'hex');
    udp.send(bytes, SERVER_PORT, SERVER_ADDR)
  });
});
```

When the test completes successfully, that code path can call `udp.close()` which lets mocha exit.

When a test exceeds mocha's 2 second time-out, I see the error but mocha does not exit as the UDP port is still listening.

Is there some form of callback/event that I can use to close a listening UDP socket when mocha's 2 second time-out fires?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved with an `afterEach` hook. An `afterEach` hook is a function that gets executed after each test, whether passed or failed (but not skipped). So it is useful to perform cleanup operations, like closing a socket in this case.

Like all [Mocha hooks](https://mochajs.org/#hooks), an `afterEach` is defined inside a `describe` function call, and it applies to all tests in that scope. If you only want the hook to run after one particular test only, put that test into a dedicated `describe` function.

So the changes to do here are the following:

- Move the declaration of `udp` from the `it` function into the containing `describe` function. This will make `udp` accesible from both `it` and `afterEach`.
- Add an `afterEach` hook to perform the cleanup operation: `udp.close();`. Remember that this will run whether the test passes or fails for any reason, so it's a good idea to avoid assumptions about the progress of the test. Here: don't assume that `udp` has been already created.
- Remove other calls to `udp.close();`, these are no longer needed now.

```js
describe('the server', function() {
  let udp;

  afterEach(() => {
    if (udp) {
      udp.close();
      udp = undefined;
    }
  });

  it('should respond to a udp packet', function(done) {
    udp = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

    udp.on('error', function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });

    udp.on('message', function(msg, rinfo) {
      console.log('msg', msg);
      console.log('rinfo', rinfo);
      // TODO: check the reply
      done();
    });
    udp.bind();

    // send a request
    const bytes = Buffer.from("421a0800117860bc457f0100001a0653455256455222054d54303031", 'hex');
    udp.send(bytes, SERVER_PORT, SERVER_ADDR)
  });
});
```

One thing to note is that in case of a timeout, the test function may keep running after the socket has been closed, producing all kinds of baffling error messages: this is not surprising.

Another interesting thing to note is that variables scoped in a `describe` function call (unlike those in an `it` function call) have the same lifetime of the Mocha run. For this reason it is a common practice to create those variable lazily when needed (in the tests) and to clear up manually by setting them explicitly to `undefined` or `null` as soon as they are no longer needed.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I hadn't considered declaring the `udp` variable outside of the `it()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `mocha --exit` which is far simpler than closing the sockets yourself.